# How can I configure my Gmail and Hotmail accounts with the Windows 8 Mail app?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-mail-app

As I am new to Windows 8 & the Metro app configuration, I would like someone to guide me on how can I configure my existing  GMail & Hotmail account to the Windows 8 Metro app.

Comment: Simply asking for experiences invites everyone to post their own answer, which we don't encourage. Please keep your question reasonably scoped – experiences are somewhat subjective in nature. Also, what have you tried yet? Have you attempted to add your Gmail account to the app? If so, where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are in the Mail app, move your mouse pointer to one of the right corners (top or bottom) and let the `Charms Bar` appear. Alternatively, you can also press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Now, click on Settings and in the next screen click on Accounts. There, you will see a list which includes among others Hotmail and Gmail. Click on the relevant type and enter your details. Voila! Your accounts are configured.

I'm unable to provide screenshots now as I'm not logged into Windows, so use this source if you want visual help. http://winsupersite.com/article/windows8/windows-8-tip-adding-accounts-mail-app-143395